# Date field not visible in one form records and is visible in other form records in InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I have a InfoPath form connected to a XML SharePoint library. I made some changes in InfoPath form and published it.

Since field is visible in all form records in library but not visible in only one record.